# Issues turning a piece of code into a function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to turn a bit of code into a function that can be applied to multiple data sets, but am having some issues.

**Code**

```
library(FSA)
library(dplyr)

blg.eqn <- wsVal("Bluegill", units="metric")
lmb.eqn <- wsVal("Largemouth Bass", units="metric")

## filter out individuals below the minimum size
test <- df_new  %>%
  subset(species == "BLG" & length_mm >= blg.eqn$min.TL |
           species == "LMB" & length_mm >= lmb.eqn$min.TL) 

test$W_s <- ifelse(test$species == "BLG",
                   10^(blg.eqn$int + blg.eqn$slope*log10(test$length_mm)), 
                   ifelse(test$species == "LMB", 
                          10^(lmb.eqn$int + lmb.eqn$slope*log10(test$length_mm)), 
                          NA))

## use W_s to calculate relative weight 
test$relative_weight <- (test$wt_g/test$W_s)*100
```

I want to turn this bit of code into a function so I can put a dataframe of the same format into it and it will just add the relative weight column to it for each observation. I've tried a few variations of the following which doesn't work.

```
test <- df  %>%
  subset(species == "BLG" & length_mm >= blg.eqn$min.TL |
           species == "LMB" & length_mm >= lmb.eqn$min.TL) 

relative_weight_function <- function(df) {
  df$W_s <- ifelse(df$species == "BLG", 
                   10^(blg.eqn$int + blg.eqn$slope*log10(df$length_mm)), 
                   ifelse(df$species == "LMB", 
                          10^(lmb.eqn$int + lmb.eqn$slope*log10(df$length_mm)),
                          NA))
  df$wr <- (df$wt_g/df$W_s)*100 
}


new <- relative_weight_function(test) %>% rbind()
```

On this version of code I got it to a point where it returns the correct values, however it drops all other information and put the values into their own column labeled "V1, V2, V3....."

Any help or insight on where I'm going wrong with this would be greatly appreciated.

### data

```
df_new <- structure(list(waterbody = c("Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer"), species = c("LMB", "LMB", "GZS", "BLG", "LMB", 
"GZS", "BLG", "BLG", "BLG", "GZS", "BLG", "BLG", "LMB", "GZS", 
"LMB", "LMB", "GZS", "GOS", "LMB", "LMB"), length_mm = c(430, 
430, NA, 165, 345, NA, 128, 117, 93, NA, 135, 161, 402, NA, 347, 
450, NA, NA, 477, 255), wt_g = c(1270, 1325, NA, 108, 545, NA, 
40, 28, 15, NA, 42, 81, 865, NA, 525, 1310, NA, NA, 1650, 275
), transect_number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In another version it worked, but labels were dropped...within that approach was there a 'use.names = TRUE' type option?, or failing that, was there a regularity of assignment to 'V1:V&ect' that you could handle via `names`? Just saying, don't ignore that you got a correct value, and may not, necessarily, be something that cleanly reports in one pass. Take the correct value and relabel others?

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided the other version. I edited the post to show that. Since its a custom function it doesn't seem 'use.names' would work. I would attempt to use 'names', however, the actual datasets I'm using are very large and it would be less than ideal to deal with it that way

Comment: `cbind(test,new)`?, as they have same > length(new)
[1] 14
> dim(test)
[1] 14  5, perhaps.

Comment: I'm unclear what your values should be as`$wr` [1] 102.91092 107.36769...` or `wr <dbl> 103. 107.` ,but, either one, could be aided by `return(df)`} within the function body, that will likely make the `%>% rbind()` unnecessary.

Comment: Nothing survives the function environment upon exit, except what is returned. In the cases above it is `df$wr`, and that's it, because it was the last thing evaluated, touched, and was on the LHS, because the RHS elements of the same line didn't survive the end of the function environment. All of the cumulative df$this_thing, df$another_thing, & df$wr, were there, all strapped together, but sometimes you only want df$wr, and sometimes you want df.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to take a look at this when I can later tonight. Really appreciate your input. I think something like a cbind() might be the way to go with it- not sure why I didn't think of that before. Thanks again!